# Symfony 1.4.6 loading factories.yml configuration from task

Tags: php, configuration, symfony1, yaml, factories

I have the following configuration set in my factories.yml file...

```
all:
  mailer:
    param:
      transport:
        class: Swift_SendmailTransport
        param:
          command: /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

...to overcome the 'double dot' issue as described [here](http://swiftmailer.lighthouseapp.com/projects/21527/tickets/113-quoted-printable-soft-line-breaks-problem).

When I run the following code...

```
$mailer = $this->getMailer();
$message = $mailer->compose();

$message->setTo('foo@bar.com');
$message->setFrom('foo@bar.com');
$message->setSubject('Testing');
$message->setBody(
  $mailer->getRealtimeTransport()->getCommand(),
  'text/plain'
);

$mailer->send($message);
```

...inside an action everything works as expected. But when I run the same code from inside a task, I get a fatal error - `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method getCommand` - because SwiftMailer is using the default transport class and not the `Swift_SendmailTransport` class as specified in the factories.yml configuration.

Any ideas why the factories.yml configuration isn't loaded in a symfony task, and how I can go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your task doesn't know which application's factories.yml to load - even if you only have one app. You need to pass an application parameter like this:

```
php symfony namespace:task --application=frontend
```

To have a default app in your task, update your configure like this:

```
protected function configure()
{
  $this->addOptions(array(
    new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'frontend'),
  ));
}
```